Why do we need to consider interaction for doping atom?
In semiconductors, the intrinsic carrier concentration is calculated by Fermi-Dirac distribution, but for the situation of doping, we need to consider the Coulomb interaction for doping atom, and the double occupancy is forbidden, we have ($\mu$ is the Feimi energy)
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}exp(\frac{E_D-\mu}{k_BT})+1}.$$
But why? The electron density of the intrinsic carrier is more than the latter, why do not consider interaction for both of situations?
My question is in what situation we need to consider interaction?
Here's a excerpt from the textbook (and Eq.(2.24) is F-D distribution function)


You should improve the formulation of your question. Please explain what you mean by "interaction" and "both of them". Also, if $E_D$ is an energy, your expression is dimensionally incorrect.

Thank you for your comment, I revised the problem

The ground (or any other) state of a donor impurity consisting of a localized center with a single positive elementary charge can only be occupied with a single electron with either spin up or down. The reason is very simple: when the positively charged center is occupied by the negatively charged electron, it becomes neutral and its energy states effectively "don't exist" for other electrons anymore. This is similar to the situation of a hydrogen nucleus (proton). When it is occupied by an electron in a bound hydrogen atom state, it becomes a neutral hydrogen atom and the remaining hydrogen atom states do not exist for other electrons any longer. A similar consideration holds for a negative acceptor impurity binding a hole.
PS: If you go into the details, the situation is more complicated, as is already indicated by the quote you made from your book. The repulsion of the second electron plays an important role in the energy levels. Thus, if you have a donor with two electrons, the ionization energy to remove the first electron is much smaller than the one for the second electron. Therefore, considering the electron occupation statistics for the single ionized impurity and the double ionized impurity, you have actually two very different energy levels. In other words,  the lowest energy level of the fully ionized donor changes strongly upon occupation with the second electron. This is analogous to He where the removal of the first electron requires less than half the energy of the removal energy of the second.

But how about the situation for donor( or acceptor )with more than one electrons?

@orz The simplest case would be analogous to the Helium atom. An ionized impurity with two positive elementary charges. And the 1s level can be occupied with two opposite spin electrons. The acceptor is analogous.

So in this case the level can be occupied with two electrons? But because of the reason mentioned above, this situation should be forbidden.

@orz You can find a good simple description of the occupation statistics of impurities in C.-T. Sah, "Fundamentals of Solid-State Electronics", World Scientific 1991.

@orz I appended a postscript to my answer hopefully answering your last comment.

@orz A book specially dedicated to the electron statistics in semiconductors is the monograph by J.S. Blakemore, "Semiconductor Statistics", Dover 1987.

Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful
